# Datasheet view for sql table?

Tags: datasheet

I would like to manipulate an sql table via web interface in sharepoint the same way I use datasheet view for SharePoint lists.
I would be interested in any kind of a non-commercial solution.
Or would the only possiblity be to open the sql table in a client (ms office) app?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via BCS. Check this out : http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-using-bcs-with-sql.html

Comment: BCS seems not support datasheet view(http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/external-content-type-limitations). What I'm after is the excel-style datasheet view where you can, for example, copy-paste cells to/from Excel multiple rows at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple soltion connect the sql table to sharepoint using BCS you can do this easily in sharepoint designer. your interface will then be the same as a list

Comment: BCS doesn't seem to support the datasheet view (see above).